# What is the proper way to implement chat "history" like pagination with relay connections?

Tags: reactjs, relayjs

I am trying to make an example chat with relay and subscriptions.
I've managed to make it work in some fashion. 
The problem is that older messages are pushed from the view when new message is added by either mutation or subscription. But it is not an actual behavior we expect from chat. We want to all loaded messages from history stay in list when new message is added to the bottom.

[playground example(without subscription, but mutation is enough)](https://facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html#source=class%20Route%20extends%20Relay.Route%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20queries%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20(Component)%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20query%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20viewer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BComponent.getFragment('viewer')%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20static%20routeName%20%3D%20'Route'%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MsgsComponent%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20propTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20React.PropTypes.object%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('render'%2C%20this.props.viewer.msgs)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20onClick%3D%7B()%20%3D%3E%20this.loadMore()%7D%3ELoad%20one%20more%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bthis.props.viewer.msgs.edges.map((%7B%20node%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%3Cdiv%3E%7Bnode.id%7D%26nbsp%3B%7Bnode.text%7D%3C%2Fdiv%3E)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20onClick%3D%7B()%20%3D%3E%20this.addMsg()%7D%3ENew%20message%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20addMsg()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.props.relay.commitUpdate(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20new%20AddMsgMutation(%7B%20text%3A%20%22new%20msg%22%2C%20viewer%3A%20this.props.viewer%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20loadMore()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.props.relay.setVariables(%7B%20last%3A%20this.props.relay.variables.last%20%2B%201%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20MsgsContainer%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(MsgsComponent%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20initialVariables%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20last%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Viewer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20msgs(last%3A%20%24last)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cursor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pageInfo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hasNextPage%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%0Aclass%20AddMsgMutation%20extends%20Relay.Mutation%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20fragments%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Viewer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20getMutation()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mutation%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20addMsg%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20getFatQuery()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20AddMsgPayload%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20msgEdge%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20viewer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20getConfigs()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'RANGE_ADD'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20parentName%3A%20'viewer'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20parentID%3A%20this.props.viewer.id%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20connectionName%3A%20'msgs'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20edgeName%3A%20'msgEdge'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20rangeBehaviors%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20''%3A%20'append'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20getVariables()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20this.props.text%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20getOptimisticResponse()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20msgEdge%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20this.props.text%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20this.props.viewer.id%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%20%20%0AReactDOM.render(%0A%20%20%3CRelay.RootContainer%0A%20%20%20%20Component%3D%7BMsgsContainer%7D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3D%7Bnew%20Route()%7D%0A%20%20%2F%3E%2C%0A%20%20mountNode%0A)%3B&schema=import%20%7B%0A%20%20GraphQLNonNull%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLID%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLObjectType%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLSchema%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLString%2C%0A%7D%20from%20'graphql'%3B%0A%0Aimport%20%7B%0A%20%20connectionArgs%2C%0A%20%20connectionDefinitions%2C%0A%20%20connectionFromArray%2C%0A%20%20nodeDefinitions%2C%0A%20%20mutationWithClientMutationId%2C%0A%20%20cursorForObjectInConnection%2C%0A%20%20fromGlobalId%2C%0A%7D%20from%20'graphql-relay'%3B%0A%0Afunction%20getMsgs()%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20msgs%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20for%20(let%20idx%20%3D%201%3B%20idx%20%3C%3D%2010%3B%20idx%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20msgs.push(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20idx%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%60msg%24%7Bidx%7D%60%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20return%20msgs%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20msgs%20%3D%20getMsgs()%3B%0A%0Afunction%20addMsg(text)%20%7B%0A%20%20msgs.push(%7Bid%3A%20msgs.length%2C%20text%3A%20text%7D)%3B%0A%20%20return%20msgs.length%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20getMsg(id)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20msgs%5Bid%20-%201%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20%7BnodeInterface%2C%20nodeField%7D%20%3D%20nodeDefinitions(%0A%20%20(globalId)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%7Btype%2C%20id%7D%20%3D%20fromGlobalId(globalId)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(globalId%20%3D%3D%200)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20id%3A%200%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20getMsg(id)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20(obj)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('nodeDefinitions%20obj'%2C%20obj)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(obj.id%20%3D%3D%3D%200)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20viewerType%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20msgType%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A)%3B%0A%0Avar%20msgType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Msg'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20new%20GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20GraphQLString%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%0A%20%20interfaces%3A%20%5BnodeInterface%5D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20%7BconnectionType%3A%20msgConnection%2C%20edgeType%3A%20msgEdge%7D%20%3D%0A%20%20connectionDefinitions(%7Bname%3A%20'Msg'%2C%20nodeType%3A%20msgType%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20viewerType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Viewer'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20new%20GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20GraphQLString%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20msgs%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20msgConnection%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20args%3A%20connectionArgs%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20(_%2C%20args)%20%3D%3E%20connectionFromArray(msgs%2C%20args)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%0A%20%20interfaces%3A%20%5BnodeInterface%5D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20queryType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Query'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20node%3A%20nodeField%2C%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20viewerType%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20id%3A%200%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%0A%0A%20%20%0Aconst%20addMsgMutation%20%3D%20mutationWithClientMutationId(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'AddMsg'%2C%0A%20%20inputFields%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20new%20GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20outputFields%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20msgEdge%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20msgEdge%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20(%7BlocalMsgId%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20msg%20%3D%20getMsg(localMsgId)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cursor%3A%20cursorForObjectInConnection(msgs%2C%20msg)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%3A%20msg%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20viewerType%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7Breturn%20%7Bid%3A%200%7D%3B%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20mutateAndGetPayload%3A%20(%7Btext%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20localMsgId%20%3D%20addMsg(text)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7BlocalMsgId%7D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20mutationType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Mutation'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20addMsg%3A%20addMsgMutation%2C%0A%20%20%20%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Aexport%20default%20new%20GraphQLSchema(%7B%0A%20%20query%3A%20queryType%2C%0A%20%20mutation%3A%20mutationType%2C%0A%7D)%3B)

[with subscriptions](https://github.com/grinderrz/relay-sangria-example/tree/master/src/main/js/js)

### So there we have:

- *msgs* field on viewer, which is *Msg* connection.
- *AddMsg* mutation, which adds new message to the bottom (rangeBehaviors: 'append')
- *$last* variable on relay container, which gets incremented on "Load one more", making history feature work somehow.

We can increment *$last* from container but there is no way I know of to increment it on addition of new connection node in store.

Some workarounds we've thought of with my colleague:

1. Increment last in *AddMsg* mutation callback. It will work for mutation, but not for subscription. And the oldest message will be pushed out still by optimistic response, then added back again after response.
2. Try to increment *$last* in componentWillReceiveProps. This seems very hacky solution, because:

   - there is no way to safely decide what to do with *$last*, knowing previous and next props only.
   - componentWillReceiveProps will be called several times for mutation (optimistic response, than *$last* change, than actual response)
3. Do not use *$last* variable. Instead fetch msgs(last: 100000000) and make server return default count on first response (2 in out example) if *last* is big enough. In this case all will work as expected. But backend will actually fail to comply to relay-graphql connection spec.
4. Split *MsgsContainer* *viewer* fragment to 2 (or more) fragments:

   - history "... msgs(last: $last, before: $lastMsgCursor) { ..."
   - newMessages "... msgs(after: $lastMsgCursor) { ..."

   The problem here is message with $lastMsgCursor will be excluded from both history and newMessages fragments, so may be we need third fragment: lastMessage. But then, how to query it?

None of this ideas seem to be a good way to go. So I wonder, what will be proper way to make history like pagination work?

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is to ‘make room’ for the new item, perform the mutation, and rollback the room in case the mutation fails:

```js
addMsg() {
  // Make room for the new item.
  this.props.relay.setVariables({ 
    last: this.props.relay.variables.last + 1,
  });
  // Perform the mutation.
  this.props.relay.commitUpdate(
    new AddMsgMutation({ 
      text: "new msg", 
      viewer: this.props.viewer,
    }),
    {
      onFailure: () => {
        // Roll back the room if the mutation fails.
        this.props.relay.setVariables({ 
          last: this.props.relay.variables.last - 1,
        });
      },
    },
  );
}
```

Updated Playground: ([link](https://facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html#source=class%20Route%20extends%20Relay.Route%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20queries%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20(Component)%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20query%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20viewer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BComponent.getFragment('viewer')%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20static%20routeName%20%3D%20'Route'%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MsgsComponent%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20propTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20React.PropTypes.object%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('render'%2C%20this.props.viewer.msgs)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20onClick%3D%7B()%20%3D%3E%20this.loadMore()%7D%3ELoad%20one%20more%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bthis.props.viewer.msgs.edges.map((%7B%20node%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%3Cdiv%3E%7Bnode.id%7D%26nbsp%3B%7Bnode.text%7D%3C%2Fdiv%3E)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20onClick%3D%7B()%20%3D%3E%20this.addMsg()%7D%3ENew%20message%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20addMsg()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.props.relay.setVariables(%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20last%3A%20this.props.relay.variables.last%20%2B%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.props.relay.commitUpdate(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20new%20AddMsgMutation(%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%22new%20msg%22%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20this.props.viewer%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onFailure()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.props.relay.setVariables(%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20last%3A%20this.props.relay.variables.last%20-%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20loadMore()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.props.relay.setVariables(%7B%20last%3A%20this.props.relay.variables.last%20%2B%201%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20MsgsContainer%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(MsgsComponent%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20initialVariables%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20last%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Viewer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20msgs(last%3A%20%24last)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cursor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pageInfo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hasNextPage%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%0Aclass%20AddMsgMutation%20extends%20Relay.Mutation%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20fragments%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Viewer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20getMutation()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mutation%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20addMsg%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20getFatQuery()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20AddMsgPayload%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20msgEdge%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20viewer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20getConfigs()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'RANGE_ADD'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20parentName%3A%20'viewer'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20parentID%3A%20this.props.viewer.id%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20connectionName%3A%20'msgs'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20edgeName%3A%20'msgEdge'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20rangeBehaviors%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20''%3A%20'append'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20getVariables()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20this.props.text%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20getOptimisticResponse()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20msgEdge%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20this.props.text%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20this.props.viewer.id%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%20%20%0AReactDOM.render(%0A%20%20%3CRelay.RootContainer%0A%20%20%20%20Component%3D%7BMsgsContainer%7D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3D%7Bnew%20Route()%7D%0A%20%20%2F%3E%2C%0A%20%20mountNode%0A)%3B&schema=import%20%7B%0A%20%20GraphQLNonNull%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLID%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLObjectType%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLSchema%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLString%2C%0A%7D%20from%20'graphql'%3B%0A%0Aimport%20%7B%0A%20%20connectionArgs%2C%0A%20%20connectionDefinitions%2C%0A%20%20connectionFromArray%2C%0A%20%20nodeDefinitions%2C%0A%20%20mutationWithClientMutationId%2C%0A%20%20cursorForObjectInConnection%2C%0A%20%20fromGlobalId%2C%0A%7D%20from%20'graphql-relay'%3B%0A%0Afunction%20getMsgs()%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20msgs%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20for%20(let%20idx%20%3D%201%3B%20idx%20%3C%3D%2010%3B%20idx%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20msgs.push(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20idx%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%60msg%24%7Bidx%7D%60%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20return%20msgs%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20msgs%20%3D%20getMsgs()%3B%0A%0Afunction%20addMsg(text)%20%7B%0A%20%20msgs.push(%7Bid%3A%20msgs.length%2C%20text%3A%20text%7D)%3B%0A%20%20return%20msgs.length%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20getMsg(id)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20msgs%5Bid%20-%201%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20%7BnodeInterface%2C%20nodeField%7D%20%3D%20nodeDefinitions(%0A%20%20(globalId)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%7Btype%2C%20id%7D%20%3D%20fromGlobalId(globalId)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(globalId%20%3D%3D%200)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20id%3A%200%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20getMsg(id)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20(obj)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('nodeDefinitions%20obj'%2C%20obj)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(obj.id%20%3D%3D%3D%200)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20viewerType%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20msgType%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A)%3B%0A%0Avar%20msgType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Msg'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20new%20GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20GraphQLString%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%0A%20%20interfaces%3A%20%5BnodeInterface%5D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20%7BconnectionType%3A%20msgConnection%2C%20edgeType%3A%20msgEdge%7D%20%3D%0A%20%20connectionDefinitions(%7Bname%3A%20'Msg'%2C%20nodeType%3A%20msgType%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20viewerType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Viewer'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20new%20GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20GraphQLString%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20msgs%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20msgConnection%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20args%3A%20connectionArgs%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20(_%2C%20args)%20%3D%3E%20connectionFromArray(msgs%2C%20args)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%0A%20%20interfaces%3A%20%5BnodeInterface%5D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20queryType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Query'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20node%3A%20nodeField%2C%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20viewerType%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20id%3A%200%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%0A%0A%20%20%0Aconst%20addMsgMutation%20%3D%20mutationWithClientMutationId(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'AddMsg'%2C%0A%20%20inputFields%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20new%20GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20outputFields%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20msgEdge%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20msgEdge%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20(%7BlocalMsgId%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20msg%20%3D%20getMsg(localMsgId)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cursor%3A%20cursorForObjectInConnection(msgs%2C%20msg)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%3A%20msg%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20viewerType%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7Breturn%20%7Bid%3A%200%7D%3B%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20mutateAndGetPayload%3A%20(%7Btext%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20localMsgId%20%3D%20addMsg(text)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7BlocalMsgId%7D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20mutationType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Mutation'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20addMsg%3A%20addMsgMutation%2C%0A%20%20%20%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Aexport%20default%20new%20GraphQLSchema(%7B%0A%20%20query%3A%20queryType%2C%0A%20%20mutation%3A%20mutationType%2C%0A%7D)%3B))

Comment: Thanks for response! So this is basically №1. from my list. And it doesn't solve subscription based message. Maybe subscription mechanism must have ability to register callback on new message too.

Comment: I would agree with that! I would certainly like to be able to listen for new data coming down the pipe as a result of a subscription.